# When should I close Facebook session (Android)?

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

In my android app, I have 3 login options. Google+, Facebook, and my own login option. I've implemented all 3.

I've implemented Facebook login via their v3.0 sdk. I open a Session, get an Access Token and the user's id. I then pass these 2 values to my api and log them in.

After getting those 2 values, I have no other use for facebook and I want to close the Session. Is there any reason I should leave it open?

I have a similar question for GoogleApiClient [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043349/when-should-i-disconnect-googleapiclient-android)

Comment: If you don't ever do anything with the Session, then there's no reason to keep it open, but there's no reason to explicitly close it either (since it doesn't do anything in the background).